# Technical Analysis - OBV indicator calculation in R

Tags: r, indicator, trading, algorithmic-trading

Here is a few references about OBV calculations:

1. http://ta.mql4.com/indicators/volumes/on_balance_volume
2. http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:on_balance_volume_obv
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-balance_volume

When I navigate to the source code of OBV function in TTR package, I see:

```
"OBV" <-
function(price, volume) {
    # On Balance Volume
    price <- try.xts(price, error=as.matrix)
    volume <- try.xts(volume, error=as.matrix)

    if(!(is.xts(price) && is.xts(volume))) {
        price <- as.vector(price)
        volume <- as.vector(volume)
    }
    obv <- c( volume[1], ifelse( ROC(price) > 0, volume, -volume )[-1] )
    obv <- cumsum( obv )
    if(is.xts(obv)) {
        obv <- xts(obv,index(price))
        colnames(obv) <- 'obv'
    }
    reclass( obv, price )
}
```

I see that the equality case (I mean the case occurs when today’s close is equal to yesterday’s close) in the reference web pages does not exist in OBV function implementation.

Is it a bug or an acceptance of the package? If it is a bug, where can I report the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: You should ask the package maintainer, and report potential bugs to them.

Comment: In that page http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html I see the @JoshuaUlrich as the author of the package. Is that you? :) If not who is the package maintainer?

Comment: Yes, I'm the maintainer of TTR. My point is that you should usually ask the package maintainer if something is a bug or "an acceptance of the package".  They are more likely to know than random R users who follow StackOverflow.  And many packages on CRAN have a "Bug Reports" URL email or email address link on the CRAN page.

Comment: Thank you; I appreciate the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, so [I've reported it](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR).  I should be able to fix it sometime over the next few days.

In general, you should ask the package maintainer (which happens to be me in this case) because they are more likely to know whether or not something is a bug than the general audience on stackoverflow.